# What is the meaning of the phrase "as it were"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

In older texts, one can find the phrase "**as it were**".

Is it similiar in meaning to the contemporary phrase, "**as if**"?

> The little girl placed teacups in front of Mr. Bear and Dolly, ***as if*** her two stuffed animals were fast friends or siblings.

Comment: Have you looked the string up in dictionaries, Samuel? Don't they help?

Comment: The meanings aren't really the same. You can't usually replace ***as it were*** by ***as if***, but you *can* usually substitute ***so to speak*** without changing the meaning. Except ***so to speak*** is a bit "colloquial" - to retain approximately the same register you could perhaps replace ***as it were*** by ***if you will***.

Comment: It is an idiom in contemporary English too. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_it_were

Answer (score 1):

[**as it were**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-it-were) <sup><sub>(Cambridge Dictionary)</sub></sup>
***idiom***
sometimes said after a figurative (= not meaning exactly what it appears to mean) or unusual expression:
*If he still refuses we could always apply a little pressure, as it were.*

...where *as it were* implies that when the speaker said *apply a little pressure*, she probably meant *apply a **lot** of pressure* (perhaps by sending ["the heavy mob"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-heavy-mob) round to beat him up if he still refuses to do what she and her friends want).